# Specifically point to a list in a for loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a class called Config with an object called "ip_list". There are two lists called ip_list1 and ip_list2. What I want to do is iterate though one of the ip lists based on a user selection. A simple version of my code is here:

```
ip_list1 = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4']
ip_list2 = ['192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.6', '192.168.1.7', '192.168.1.8']

class Config: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip_list = ""

list = int(input("Chose ip list: ")

if list == 1:
    Config.ip_list = "ip_list1"
elif list == 2:
    Config.ip_list = "ip_list2"
else:
    print(f"{list} is an invalid choice")

for ip in Config.ip_list:
    <do something>
```

This obviously doesn't work or I wouldn't be asking the question :)
It iterates through each letter of the actual string "ip_listx". How do I get it to point to the list and not just use the string?

Comment: You set it to the string and not the list, did you mean `Config.ip_list = ip_list1` rather than `Config.ip_list = "ip_list1"`?

Comment: I can't believe that it is that easy to fix....I feel like such a dummy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with the code:

1. `list` is a data structure in python. Try renaming the variable from `list` to something else like `foo`.
2. You're using `int()` to handle taking an input but there's a syntax error because you forgot to include the trailing bracket for `int()`.
   It should be `foo = int(input("Choose ip list: "))`.
   Sample:

```
ip_list1 = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4']
ip_list2 = ['192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.6', '192.168.1.7', '192.168.1.8']

class Config: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip_list = ""

foo = int(input("Chose ip list: "))

if foo == 1:
    Config.ip_list = "ip_list1"
elif foo == 2:
    Config.ip_list = "ip_list2"
else:
    print(f"{foo} is an invalid choice")

for ip in Config.ip_list:
    print(ip)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Config()
```

Comment: Thanks, zngrm, for the response! I understand what you are saying. This was just a quick example of what I am trying to do. I am not really using "list" as a variable. I wasn't thinking about that when I put this snippet together.